# Performance server scripting

Tags: google-app-maker

I have table with multiple customerKey values assigned to a numeric value; I wrote a script where foreach row of data I scan whole table to find all values assigned to the current customerKey and return a highest one;

I have a problem with performance - script processes around 10 records per second - any ideas how to improve this or maybe propose an alternative solution plesae?

```
function getLastest() {
    var date = app.models.magicMain.newQuery();
    var date_all = date.run();

    date_all.forEach(function(e) { // for every row of date_all
        var temp = date_all.filter(function(x) {
            return x.SubscriberKey === e.SubscriberKey; // find matching records for the current x.SubscriberKey
        });
        var dates = [];
        temp.forEach(function(z) { // get all matching "dates"
            dates.push(z.Date);
        });
        var finalValue = dates.reduce(function(a, b) { // get highest dates value (integer)
            return Math.max(a, b);
        });

        var record = app.models.TempOperatoins.newRecord(); // save results to DB
        record.email = e.SubscriberKey.toString() + " " + finalValue.toString();
        app.saveRecords([record]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only suggestion I have would be to add:

var recordstosave = [];

At the top of your function.
Then replace app.saveRecords([record]) with recordstosave.push(record).

Finally outside of your foreach function do app.saveRecords(recordstosave).

I saw major processing time improvements doing this rather than saving each record individually inside a loop.